# MySQL Prepared Statement with a null String

Tags: java, mysql, testing

I am doing software testing on an application someone else wrote. When they check if a user's `username` and `password` is in the database they just send what ever `String` is passed from the GUI to the database without any check -- I know this is bad already.

I am aware that this could lead to SQL injections. However, SQL injections aside, is there any other risk? It seems that the null gets turned into something like this after it enters the semi-prepared statement in the DataBase Manager class.

```
String s = "select * from user where" + user;
```

It just ends up as this when I print it:

> select * from user wherenull

Should I fail this test case and say this program is not properly checking inputs before sending them to DB, even if it doesn't log in the user?

Comment: I'd fail it - it's also weird that you get `select * from user wherenull` - there's no column name in the where clause, which makes it appear to me that the sql is being built dynamically, and is likely to be used in more than one place, and you'll see similar behaviour in other places in the application

Comment: Java's `+` operator, when applied to `Strings` or to one `String` and something of another type, will put the four characters `'n' 'u' 'l' 'l'` in the result if an operand is `null`.